# 3 node Elasticsearch Cluster V 7xxx

Tags: elasticsearch

When I create 3 node cluster what would be the elaticsearch.yml and Kibana.yml configuration look like?

**My current configuration**

```
Node    Host    IP
Node 1  app1    192.168.60.4
Node 2  app2    192.168.60.5
Node 3  DB  192.168.60.6 

[root@orc-app1 ~]# cat /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
cluster.name: ElasticDemO
node.name: {HOSTNAME} network.host: 192.168.60.4 discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1 xpack.security.enabled: false bootstrap.system_call_filter: true path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch discovery.seed_hosts: 192.168.60.4:9300 cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["{HOSTNAME}"]
http.cors.enabled: true`

[root@orc-app1 ~]# cat /etc/kibana/kibana.yml
server.port: 5601
server.host: "192.168.60.4"
server.name: "orc-app1.dev"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://192.168.60.4:9200"]
kibana.index: ".kibana"
```

like above I have configured elasticsearch.yml and Kibana.yml accordingly

Thank you,

Nuwan

Comment: what is ur issue, are you not able to start all your service?

Comment: I can start all the services  but when I check cluster members from below command I can only see single node http://192.168.60.4:9200/_cat/nodes?v

Comment: My Elasticsearch configuration file looks like below -```cluster.name: ElasticDemO
node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
network.host: 192.168.60.4
xpack.security.enabled: false
bootstrap.system_call_filter: true
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.60.4","192.168.60.5","192.168.60.6"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["192.168.60.4","192.168.60.5","192.168.60.6"]
http.cors.enabled: true
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
node.master: true```

Comment: can you please mention which of the three nodes are master-eligible or you left the default configuration in all the three nodes?

Comment: btw discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes is ignored in version above 7 you can have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html